# Bootstrap not rendering dark background to text

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am new to using Bootstrap and was trying out some basic functionalities which did not seem to render. I was attempting to create text with a dark and darker background and the text renders, however it does so without the dark background. does not

```
<title>Bootstrap Layouts</title>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-    theme.min.css">



</head>
 <body>
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="row">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <div class="darkBG clm-sm-6">Test</div>
    <div class="darkerBG clm-sm-6">Test</div>
</div>
</div>


<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js">
</script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>enter code here
```

Comment: What is the CSS for `darkBG` and `darkerBG`?

Comment: This link mimics your code and works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/XT7LN/2/

Answer (score 0):

`<div class="darkBG clm-sm-6>` should be changed to `<div class="darkBG col-sm-6>`